# How can I customize the minus sign while formatting locale-specific numbers?

Tags: python, printf, locale, format-string

When using `sprintf` (Python in the example) there is a number of formatting options:

```
In [1]: import locale
In [2]: print locale.format_string("%+.1f%%", 1234.567)
+1234.6%

In [3]: print locale.format_string("%+.1f%%", -1234.567)
-1234.6%
```

However, I haven't yet found a way to format the actual minus sign -- e.g., I'd like it to be a proper minus to better align with the plus sign, i.e. `u"\u00B1"`. Is there any way to define this, short of doing a string replacement?

Comment: `[locale.currency](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.currency)` uses `negative_sign` locale parameter, but it's far from convenient.